# How to update JsValue?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

`JsValue` is a [trait](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJson). It might be an object of anything ex. `JsArray`, `JsObject` etc. Given a function Ex.

```
override def update(Id: String, jsValue: JsValue): Future[Option[Person]] = {
import utils.MongoFormats.dateTimeWriteFormat
execFindAndUpdate(
  _.findAndUpdate(
    Json.obj("xyz_ID" -> id),
    Json.obj("$set" -> jsValue),
    fetchNewObject = true
  )
) map { response =>
  logger.info(s"MongoDB response: $response")
  response.result[Person]
}
}
```

I want to add `updatedAt` while writing to `mongoDB`. Inshort i want to update the `jsValue`.
i tried doing

> Json.obj("$set" -> jsValue, "$set" -> Json.obj("updatedAt" -> Json.toJson(new DateTime())))

but failed.

FYI I am using `scala` `2.6.x` and `reactiveMongo` version `0.12.7-play26`
Can anyone help me on this, please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

But you know that you can update only if you have JsObject. For other cases this will be meaningless, right? So solution will be to check and update only in this case:

```
override def update(Id: String, jsValue: JsValue): Future[Option[Person]] = {
  import utils.MongoFormats.dateTimeWriteFormat
  execFindAndUpdate(
    _.findAndUpdate(
      Json.obj("xyz_ID" -> id),
      Json.obj("$set" -> (jsValue match {
        case o: JsObject => o + ("updatedAt" -> Json.toJson(new DateTime()))
        case o => o
      })),
      fetchNewObject = true
    )
  ) map { response =>
    logger.info(s"MongoDB response: $response")
    response.result[Person]
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess we can add it to `JsArray` as well?

Comment: You cannot add named fields in array. At least in play-json

Comment: Json.obj("$set" -> (jsValue match {
          case o: JsObject => o + ("updatedAt" -> Json.toJson(new DateTime()))
          case o: JsArray => o :+ Json.obj("updatedAt" -> Json.toJson(new DateTime()))
          case o => o
        }))

Comment: Ok.. But it is array element. And unlike of JsObject you can add any number of such elements, which make them meaningless..